# When user try to login always return to login page not to home page

Tags: reactjs

Heres what am trying to do. When i enters user credentials for login it sets tokens correctly in local storage but it doesn't navigate to the home page only flashes and turn back to the same login page.

i can't figure out where am geting wrong since am new to react and react-router-dom v6

login code snippet

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  
  
  const {user,isLoading, isError, isSuccess,message} = useSelector((state) => state.auth)
  

  useEffect(() => {
   

    if(isError){
      toast.error(message);
    }
    if(isSuccess || user){
      
      const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
      navigate(from, { replace: true });
    
     }
    dispatch(reset());

  },[isError,isSuccess,message,user,navigate, dispatch])
```

protected routes

```
import {Navigate,Outlet,useLocation} from "react-router-dom"
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';


const protectedRoute= () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const {user} = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

    if(user === undefined){
        return null;
    }
    return user ? (<Outlet/>) : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{from: location}} />

}

export default protectedRoute;
```

routing component

```
function Layout() {
  const Feed = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <main>
          <LeftBar />
          <div className='container'>
            <ProtectedRoute element={<Outlet/>}/>
          
          </div>
          <RightBar />
        </main>
      </>
    );
  };

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <Feed/>,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          element: <Home />,
        },
        {
          path: '/profile/:id',
          element: <Profile />,
        },
        {
          path: '/chatbox/:id',
          element: <Chatbox />,
        },
      ],
    },
    // public routes
    {
      path: '/login',
      element: <Signin />,
    },
    {
      path: '/signup',
      element: <Signup />,
    },
  ]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default Layout;
```